# Why does Windows Docker container not wait for exe to finish installing?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm writing a Dockerfile to install an exe on Windows Server 2019 and then run the installed program after.

In the Dockerfile, I call `ENTRYPOINT ["test.exe", "-f", "params.txt"]` followed by `WORKDIR "C:\Program Files\TestInstall\bin"`, but the `WORKDIR` fails to execute because the `bin` folder hasn't been created yet. I have confirmed this by running a `dir` in between the commands to check what's in the `TestInstall` directory, and each time, the `bin` folder hasn't been created yet. However, if I open a shell session after the container exits, the `bin` folder will be there.

Is there a way to make it wait for the exe to finish installing before running the `WORKDIR`, or is it dependent on how the exe performs the install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is used to specify a command that will be executed when the container starts. This means that the `bin` directory will not exist when you use `workdir`, since `ENTRYPOINT ["test.exe", "-f", "params.txt"]` was not executed yet.

You can see it as if the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is the last line that will run in your script (that's probably the reason of why it's usually placed in the end of the `Dockerfile`.)

A `RUN` instruction can be used to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the solution I was looking for. I'd actually tried the RUN instruction before, but I think I hadn't formatted the parameters properly before, so that'd caused it to fail.

Comment: @Matt Happy to help ^^